# « On n’aperçoit guère le raccord de ces deux planches »

Tags: sens, expressions

Je vous demande conseil pour saisir cette [tournure](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/raccord) que j’ai trouvée sur le Wiktionnaire. Elle sert à éclaircir l’emploi du mot *raccord*.

> « On n’aperçoit pas le raccord de ces deux planches. »

Le mot *raccord* veut dire « l’ajustage des parties dissemblables ». Je pense donc que la tournure veut dire qu’on a uni ces planches avec soin. Quelqu’un qui dit cette phrase est heureux de voir comment on a mis ensemble ces planches, peut-être même qu'il est impressionné.

**Mes questions**

- Est-ce que j’ai bien compris la tournure ?
- Est-il sage de l’apprendre. Autrement dit, est-ce qu’on me comprend facilement si je l’utilise, et est-ce qu’on la rencontre souvent ?
- Selon le Wiktionnaire, « raccord » peut être utilisé de façon figurée. C’est aussi vrai pour l’expression plus haut, ou est-ce qu’une utilisation figurée serait recherchée selon vous ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu as bien compris le sens du mot.

Le mot raccord est utile à connaître dans la mesure où il peut être difficile de le remplacer par un autre, il est employé dans de très nombreux domaines, maçonnerie, plomberie, peinture, couture, cinéma, menuiserie, etc.  L'emploi que le [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/raccord) qualifie de « figuré » ne me semble pas figuré, car même s'il s'agit d'une œuvre littéraire le raccord consiste toujours à mettre bout à bout deux morceaux en cherchant bien sûr à faire que le point de contact soit le moins visible possible. Ce point de contact que ce soit dans un discours, une pièce de théâtre (l'exemple du Wiktionnaire) ou autre, est quelque chose de tout à fait concret dans la mesure où ça se voit ou s'entend.

Comment: En l'occurrence, "figuré" est correct: c'est la première définition qui n'est pas rédigée pour la limiter aux raccords *physiques*. Mais il est vrai qu'on pourrait aisément combiner ces définitions. C'est d'ailleurs ce que fait le Robert.

Answer (score 1):

> Est-ce que j’ai bien compris la tournure ?

Oui, tu as bien compris la définition

> Est-il sage de l’apprendre. Autrement dit, est-ce qu’on me comprend facilement si je l’utilise, et est-ce qu’on la rencontre souvent ?

Sans le rencontrer très souvent, tout le monde comprendra ce que tu veux dire par raccord.

> Selon le Wiktionnaire, « raccord » peut être utilisé de façon figurée. C’est aussi vrai pour l’expression plus haut, ou est-ce qu’une utilisation figurée serait recherchée selon vous ?

Je ne suis pas sûr de bien comprendre ta dernière question. L'exemple que tu indiques utilise *raccord* au sens propre. L'utilisation au sens figuré est tout à fait possible, signifiera la même chose, et sera comprise de la même manière par tes interlocuteurs.